# I got this error during migration in truffle. : ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, dapps, truffle-migration, truffle-test

This is my smartcontract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DappToken{


uint256 public totalSupply;

constructor DappToken() public{
    totalSupply = 10000;    

 }

}
```

This is code for migration in truffle.

```
const Dapptoken = artifacts.require("DappToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {

deployer.deploy(Dapptoken);
```

> Blockquote

};

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Prior to Solidity v0.4.21:**

```
contract ContractName {
    function ContractName(...) public {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Solidity v0.4.21 onward:**

```
contract ContractName {
    constructor(...) public {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**The reason:**

In the older version, if you renamed the contract but forgot to rename the constructor, the latter would turn into a public function which anyone could execute at will. Subsequently, terrible things could happen to the state (funds and variables) of your contract. BTW, this is based on a true story.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor functions should not have a name. Just this will do fine as a constructor:

```
constructor() public {
    totalSupply = 10000;    

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `DappToken` from after `constructor`, then your problem is fixed